# GAE tasks and execution rate

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

No matter what I set rate and bucket_size I always see only one or two tasks running in the same time. Does anyone know what might be the reason?

My queue configuration is:

- name: MyQueue
  rate: 30/s
  bucket_size: 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the documentation mentions

> To ensure that the taskqueue system does not overwhelm your
>   application, it may throttle the rate at which requests are sent. This
>   throttled rate is known as the enforced rate. The enforced rate may be
>   decreased when your application returns a 503 HTTP response code, or
>   if there are no instances able to execute a request for an extended
>   period of time.

In such situations, the admin console will show an Enforced Rate lower than the 30/s you requested.